# Update bulk number of records in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, bulkupdate

I am new to sql. Can someone help me with this requirement.

I have table with 10000 records like this

```
CompanyID         Name 
300001            A
300004            B
300005            C
300007            D
|
|
|
310000            XXX
```

And I have a another list of companyIDs that I am going to update the above table(It is just an excel sheet not a table)

```
OldID       NewID
300001      500001
300002      500002
300003      500003
300004      500004
300005      500005
|
|
310000      510000
```

My requirement is, If I found the companyID in the first table I need to update it with the NewID and If I didn't find the companyId in the first table I have to create a new row in the table with the NewID regardless of oldID.

Is there any possibility to do both update and insert in a single query?

Comment: You can use MERGE statement to UPDATE and INSERT in single query block.

Comment: You can't @Incognito; a MERGE can't update a column that's referenced in the ON clause (and the ID will need to be in this case)

Comment: @Ben My bad. You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing an "upsert" or [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement, typically:

```
merge into table_a
using (<some_statement>)
   on (<some_condition>)
 when matched then
      update
         set ...
 when not matched then
      insert (<column_list>)
      values (<column_list>);
```

However, a MERGE can't update a value that's referenced in the ON clause, which is what will be required in order to do what you're asking. You will, therefore, require two statements:

```
update table_to_be_updated t
   set companyid =  (select newid from new_table where oldid = t.companyid )

insert into table_to_be_updated
select newid
  from newtable t
 where not exists ( select 1 
                      from table_to_be_updated
                     where t.newid = companyid )
```

If it's possible for a `newid` and an `oldid` to be the same then you're going to run into problems. This also assumes that your new table is unique on `oldid` *and* `newid` - it has to be unique in order to do what you want so I don't think this is an unreasonable assumption.

Comment: Isn't that too complicated? As OP finally wants everything with the new ids. Row generator method would be more suitable.

Comment: I can't see how a row generator will help @Lalit; the OP already has the data and doesn't want rows generated.

Comment: Ah! sorry @Ben. I understood incorrectly. i thought OP wants to update all the rows from old_id to new_id as shown in second table. I missed to see he wants to do an upsert.

Comment: Thanks Ben..seems good.But I have only one table in the Database. The second one is not a table it's just an excel sheet. So, how can I refer the newIDs. Do I need to create a table for that? or any other way is there? Can you pls suggest me.

Comment: @SivaGV You can use an external table for that. But, you need to first save it as CSV or any delimited text file.

Comment: @SivaGV Also, if those ids are serial numbers as you have shown, then creating a table with such serial numbers would be pretty easy. For example, `WITH new_data(A,b) AS
  ( SELECT 3000001 a, 5000001 b FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT A+1, b+1 FROM new_data WHERE A < 300010 OR b < 5000010
  )
SELECT * FROM new_data;` But test things before doing anything on production :-)

Comment: @LalitKumarB  Actually those are not serial numbers like I have mentioned, those are random ones. Just for reference i have given like that

Comment: @SivaGV Then use an external table, or search how to load data from delimited text file to Oracle database. I am sure there are plenty of examples on this site.

Comment: @LalitKumarB There are some examples where we can load a csv file into a oracle table using SQL*Loader. But I am using sql+. Do you have any idea to accomplish this in sql+?

Comment: Generally, you can't load a file using SQL\*Plus @SivaGV, you will need to use external tables or SQL\*Loader. If you have SQL*Plus installed you should also have SQL\*Loader and be able to use this. There are plenty of examples on the internet, for instance [Oracle FAQs](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ). If you have another question about this then please ask one but please bear in mind that "how do you do it" isn't a fantastic question - it's worth trying something first.